# Adding current user to CC list

Tags: vba, outlook

I'm trying to combine two actions.

```
'Assign To List
ToList = Worksheets("VBA_Code").Range("B5")

'Assign CC List
CCList = Worksheets("VBA_Code").Range("B6")

On Error Resume Next
With OutMail
    .to = ToList
    .CC = CCList
    .BCC = OutApp.GetNamespace("MAPI").Session.CurrentUser.AddressEntry
```

I have a list of users to be CC'ed. I don't think I need to include the sender under BCC, as the code above does, so I wanted to include the sender in my CC, along with the list of those in the CC list.

Is there a way to combine those two actions/calls?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The To, CC and BCC list in Outlook are semi-colon delimited.  So, just append like so:

```
.CC = CCList & ";" & OutApp.GetNamespace("MAPI").Session.CurrentUser.AddressEntry
```

Comment: that was it!  I was close.  Only adding one "&" between the two calls.  Thanks!